# In MariaDB, function placed in a trigger starts returns a different value

Tags: mysql, triggers, binary, uuid, mariadb

There are such table and functions:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (`ID` BINARY(16)) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE FUNCTION `UUID_ENCODE`(`uuid` CHAR(36))
    RETURNS binary(16)
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    RETURN UNHEX(REVERSE(REPLACE(uuid,'-','')));
END

CREATE FUNCTION `UUID_DECODE`(`uuid` BINARY(16))
    RETURNS char(36)
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
RETURN LOWER(CONCAT_WS('-',
    REVERSE(HEX(RIGHT(uuid,6))),
    REVERSE(HEX(MID(uuid,9,2))),
    REVERSE(HEX(MID(uuid,7,2))),
    REVERSE(HEX(MID(uuid,5,2))),
    REVERSE(HEX(LEFT(uuid,4)))
));
END
```

Insert is working properly:

```
INSERT INTO test (ID) VALUES(UUID_ENCODE('323febe6-cd89-4773-a46c-aab794fb7cbc'));

SELECT UUID_DECODE(ID) FROM test;
+--------------------------------------+
| uuid_decode(id)                      |
+--------------------------------------+
| 323febe6cd89-4773-a46c-aab7-94fb7cbc |
+--------------------------------------+
```

Just create a trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `test_uuid_encode` BEFORE INSERT ON `test` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    SET NEW.ID = UUID_ENCODE(NEW.ID);
END
```

and get **half truncated** value in table:

```
INSERT INTO test (ID) VALUES('323febe6-cd89-4773-a46c-aab794fb7cbc');

Warning (Code 1265): Data truncated for column 'ID' at row 1

SELECT UUID_DECODE(ID) FROM test;
+--------------------------------------+
| uuid_decode(id)                      |
+--------------------------------------+
| 000000000000-0000-0032-3feb-e6cd8947 |
+--------------------------------------+
```

What is wrong with this trigger?

Software version is:

> Ver 5.5.33a-MariaDB for Win64 on x86 (mariadb.org binary distribution)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ID` column of your table is declared as `BINARY(16)`, and your `UUID_ENCODE` expects a `CHAR(36)`. When you invoke your `UUID_ENCODE` function directly without a trigger, it correctly receives your 36 characters string. When you use the trigger instead, the value you are inserting is first converted to the type of the column, so `NEW.ID` will contain the results of `CAST('323febe6-cd89-4773-a46c-aab794fb7cbc' AS BINARY(16)`. When the trigger invokes the function, it will cast again the value of `NEW.ID` to the type expected by your function. So, this is the value your function will receive:

```
SELECT CAST(CAST('323febe6-cd89-4773-a46c-aab794fb7cbc' AS BINARY(16)) AS CHAR);

323febe6-cd89-47
```

As you can see, your function receives the value truncated. The results you are getting are equivalent to:

```
SELECT UUID_DECODE(UUID_ENCODE('323febe6-cd89-47'));

000000000000-0000-0032-3feb-e6cd8947
```

**UPDATE**

One way to implement the desired functionality in a trigger would be to add a dummy nullable column with the type your function expects:

```
CREATE TABLE test (ID BINARY(16) KEY DEFAULT 0, CHARID CHAR(36) NULL);

CREATE TRIGGER test_uuid_encode BEFORE INSERT ON test FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    SET NEW.ID = UUID_ENCODE(NEW.CHARID)
      , NEW.CHARID = NULL;
END
```

This way you can do:

```
INSERT test (CHARID) VALUES ('323febe6-cd89-4773-a46c-aab794fb7cbc');

SELECT UUID_DECODE(ID) FROM test;
+--------------------------------------+
| uuid_decode(id)                      |
+--------------------------------------+
| 323febe6cd89-4773-a46c-aab7-94fb7cbc |
+--------------------------------------+
```

I created a fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/199db/2).

Note that:

- Although `CHARID` accepts NULLs, `ID` does not, so an attempt to insert a NULL value in `CHARID` would result in the trigger trying to set `ID` to NULL and the insertion being rejected.
- Attempting to insert an invalid value into `CHARID` that causes `UUID_ENCODE` to return NULL will also fail.
- The `DEFAULT 0` clause for `ID` is there only to allow you to omit the column from the insert list. The value written to the table will always be the one generated by your trigger.
- A nullable column that is always NULL should take between 0 and 2 bytes of additional storage per row depending on your table layout and row format (you would need to avoid for instance the `FIXED` format of the MyISAM engine).
- There are many variations possible. If you don't mind the extra storage, you can keep the `CHARID` value without setting it to NULL. If you want to allow explicit insert of binary `ID` values you can add a check to the trigger so you compute `NEW.ID` only if it is 0, etc.
- You should have a similar trigger for UPDATE operations, if they are allowed.